# Scroll overflow bug in Chrome

Tags: jquery, datatables

Took me a while to catch it,

```
Chrome (Windows 7): 25.0.1364.152 m
Datatables: 1.9.4
jQuery: 1.8.3
jQuery-UI: 1.9.2
```

Set Chrome's Zoom to 90%:

http://jsfiddle.net/MfsWX/2/embedded/result/

http://jsfiddle.net/MfsWX/2/

Entire row in now overflowed out of the screen.

This bug can appear and disappear depending on the data inside of `<td>`s, but in this particular example - it shows clearly.

Why don't `"sScrollX": "100%"` and `"sScrollY": "100%"` work properly?

How to fix it?

FF and IE9 don't have this issue.

Please help. Thanks.

EDIT: Submitted to developer http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/14536/scroll-overflow-bug-in-chrome#Item_1, but everyone is asleep there. =)

**EDIT 2: For those who suffer =) and need temporary solution:**

```
#reports-table_wrapper {
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the only solution available:

```
#reports-table_wrapper {
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```